# Knockoutjs a method in foreach binding gets called twice sequentially

Tags: knockout.js

Even though the result of the binding looks ok, `createSubList` gets called twice sequentially behind the scene. You can check it out in a console of a browser. How can I avoid this behavior?

```
<section>
<!-- ko foreach : list1 -->
   <div data-bind='text:$data'></div>

    <!-- ko foreach : $root.createSubList($data) -->    
      <div data-bind='text:$data'></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
 <!-- /ko -->
</section>

function VM(){
  var self = this;
  self.list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  self.createSubList = function(index){
        // this method gets called twice, why?
        console.log(index);
        return ['Sub1'];
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(new VM())
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7eL2ur8o/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a number of reasons this happens. Most likely, in this case, it evaluates it once upon creation of the binding to get the initial value, and a second time when actually binding the DOM. Realize that KO is there for change tracking, and a way to know that something's changed is by reevaluating the observable property.

To see why in *this* particular case it happens twice it's probably easiest to load the unminified version of KO and set a break point.

But there's a more important point. You have a method name that starts with `create...` that you use in a binding. You should realize that you're using an *imparative* style of programming, where the bindings of Knockout are typically used for a *declarative* style.

Put differently, you should strive for your observable properties to be side-effect free and preferably even give the same result in the same context. Here's a more KO-style version of your code:

```js
function VM(){
  var self = this;
  var list1Input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  
  function createSubList(index){
        // this method gets called once
        console.log(index);
        return ['Sub1'];
  }
  
  self.list1 = list1Input.map(function(i){
    return {
      label: i,
      subItems: createSubList(i)
    };
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<section>
<!-- ko foreach : list1 -->
   <div data-bind='text: $data.label'></div>

    <!-- ko foreach : subItems -->    
      <div data-bind='text: $data'></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
 <!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to track down why this happens before posting this question, but it was hard. I'll go with a declarative style as you suggested!